# HttpWebResponse to return 300K records error C#

Tags: c#, httpwebresponse

WPF client is calling a service inside a container.  This call should return 300K records.  Records are displayed in a grid for reporting.
Problem is that this is too many records and will not return anything.
Is there a way to return this much data without batching them like 1000 records at a time?

Comment: What error? What does the code do? Neither *you* nor the server want to retrieve 300K records at once anyway. Depending on your code you may be caching all that data 3, 4 or more times. If the code retrieves a string and parses it, you have one copy in the string (never mind the response buffer), one copy in the deserialized array. If the deserializer doesn't go to the lengths System.Text.Json does, you may be using multiple times that RAM as temporary deserializer objects. The *server* may be in the same situation.

Comment: `Records are displayed in a grid for reporting` which can only display 100 items at a time, not 300K. Just loading all that in memory will make the UI slow to a crawl for no reason. That's why all grids use paging *and* virtualization through data binding. Some commercial ones provide data virtualization out of the box - they request the next few rows as the user scrolls, giving the impression of infinite scrolling without keeping everything in memory. In the built-in grids, you can handle events to load the next batch of data

Comment: You only need the full data set when you need to export it or print it. At this point you'll use very different code anyway, not try to save the grid. Using eg CsvHelper or EPPlus you can export data as CSV or Excel very easily

Comment: You may want to read up on "Paging" or "Pagination" (depending on who you ask).

Comment: Anyway HttpWebRequest is deprecated you should use HttpClient